# Generate report of Linux CPU info per core using top

Tags: python, linux

I'm writing a python script that generates a text file report of CPU usage per core. Really, what I want is the information that `top` provides once you type `1`.

However, optimally this would be returned to the terminal (just like running `top -b`) so I can `grep` etc.

Is there a way of getting this information, either with `top` or another command, in a format that I can then `grep` and handle within my python script. Thanks very much!

Comment: Can you use `mpstat` instead of `top`?

Comment: Actually yes! `mpstat` -P ALL returns data for each core.

Comment: try `mpstat -P ON`. In general, check `man mpstat` for additional options.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the "top" command from within a python script using "subprocess.run()" and get the output in the returned "CompletedProcess" instance.